# how can i start dragging one of several drawn canvas by touching that one

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a game.i want to move one of two canvas element.
i have drawn one circle and one rectangle and i want to drag rectangle.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: We'll need more information than that. Also, show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 Canvas is actually like a bitmap. You can set the colors of the pixels in it. So whatever you draw becomes pixels. i.e. an object will not be created. So if you need objects on Canvas and modify the Canvas content by modifying the properties (x, y, rotation etc.) of the objects you have to develop your own system which manages graphics on Canvas using objects. This system should clear and update the Canvas pixels using the properties of the objects. You will also have to create a display list to manage objects properly.

There are also a few libraries available for the same purpose

http://createjs.com/#!/EaselJS

http://www.kineticjs.com/